# Termios configuration

Tags: c++, objective-c, serial-port, termios

In a MAC OS X (10.10) program, I have a hard time setting up termios correctly for RS-485 serial communication (I use a starcom USB → RS-485 featuring the FTDI chip)

I need to set up the following:

> - 1 Start bit (0 bit)
> - 8 Databits
> - 1 Odd parity bit
> - 1 Stop bit (1 bit)
> - 19200 baud

Communication is binary, so there is no stop character.

Currently, I have found how to set most of the settings (see code below), but I didn't found where to tell termios I want a start bit.

```
@property(readwrite) int                   fileDescriptor;

_fileDescriptor = open(bsdPath, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK);
ioctl(_fileDescriptor, TIOCEXCL)
fcntl(_fileDescriptor, F_SETFL, 0)
tcgetattr(_fileDescriptor, &gOriginalTTYAttrs)

struct termios options = gOriginalTTYAttrs;
cfmakeraw(&options);
struct termios* rawOptions = &options;

// Timeout 100 ms
rawOptions->c_cc[VTIME] = 1;
rawOptions->c_cc[VMIN] = 0;

// 8 bits
rawOptions->c_cflag |= CS8;

// Parity ODD
rawOptions->c_cflag |= PARENB;
rawOptions->c_cflag |= PARODD;

// Stop bit (I hope it means one stop bit)
rawOptions->c_cflag = rawOptions->c_cflag & ~CSTOPB;

// Flow control none 
rawOptions->c_cflag = rawOptions->c_cflag & ~CRTSCTS;
rawOptions->c_cflag = rawOptions->c_cflag & ~(CDTR_IFLOW | CDSR_OFLOW);
rawOptions->c_cflag = rawOptions->c_cflag & ~CCAR_OFLOW;

// Turn on hangup on close (NO IDEA WHAT IT DOES)
rawOptions->c_cflag |= HUPCL;
// Set local mode on (NO IDEA WHAT IT DOES)
rawOptions->c_cflag |= CLOCAL;
// Enable receiver (USEFUL, I GUESS)
rawOptions->c_cflag |= CREAD;
// Turn off canonical mode and signals (NO IDEA WHAT IT DOES)
rawOptions->c_lflag &= ~(ICANON /*| ECHO*/ | ISIG);

// Raw (binary output)
rawOptions->c_oflag &= ~OPOST;

// 19200 baud
cfsetspeed(rawOptions, 19200);

// Applying settings
tcsetattr(_fileDescriptor, TCSANOW, rawOptions);
```

Comment: *"I didn't found where to tell termios I want a start bit"* -- There are no configuration options relating to the async start bit.  There is always a start bit in an RS232/RS485 character frame.  Your code should always be checking the return code from system calls for errors.  See [Serial Programming Guide for POSIX Operating Systems](http://www.cmrr.umn.edu/~strupp/serial.html)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Then I guess there is no "term char" also? it is up to the application to add it? ( I need "no term char" in the configuration).

Comment: Only canonical mode has end-of-line characters.  For non-canonical (i..e. raw mode) input, there is no line-discipline layer, and the message/packet/datagram has to be scanned and parsed by the application that reads the tty device-file.  Well-structured code is required for a readable and maintainable protocol implementation.

Comment: Thank you sawdust. So, I actually have to poll the interface for any new data until, after packet analysis, I determine there are no more data to receive?